# Complex html form to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http, post

I have an advanced form. Which I need to send to my restapi from a basic html page form.
My form consists of basic fields eg. Name, id and so on.
I also have a list of objects.
My problem comes when I need an object inside my object.
eg. jsonString object, which is dynamic and can contain several fields.

```
<input type="text" name="jsonString.field1" value="123">
<input type="text" name="jsonString.field2" value="qwe">
<input type="text" name="jsonString.fieldN" value="...">
```

What I want is:

```
{
id: 411421,
name: asdojasfjo,
alotOfRandomFields: "Random", 
"jsonString": { 
    field1: "123",
    field2: "qwe",
    fieldN: "..." },
numbers: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

My jsonString object field name may vary and be eg. "Petname", petage, petOwnerName and in other form it might be. "Jobname" and "salary".

I know if I save them all with the same name I get a array, but then I can't see the field names, which are needed in the future to compare all documents containing pets.

At the moment I am using jquery:

```
form.serialize();
```

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: I really don't get why people downvote questions without giving feedback why they downvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Don't really like the way it is solved. So if anyone has a better idea please share :)

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form){
    var array = jQuery(form).serializeArray();
    var json = {jsonString:{}};
    var substring = "jsonString";
    jQuery.each(array, function() {
        if(this.name.indexOf(substring) !== -1){
            json["jsonString"][this.name.substring(10)] = this.value;
        }
        else{
            json[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }

    });

    return json;
}
```